# Is possible combine multiple subsequent capture-group matchning regexes into one?

Tags: regex, perl

When saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22627550/632407), started thinking about the capture groups more deeply.

For example having the next (example) input:

```
text (aaa (text) ccc) 
text ( aaa (text) ccc )
text ( ' aaa (text) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa (text) ccc " )
text (aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc) 
text ( aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc )
text ( ' aaa ( " text " ) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc " )
```

and want capture **anyhing** what is in place of `aaa` `text` (at the middle) and `ccc`, so the wanted result:

```
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
```

I have 3 regex solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    m/
        .*?     #non greedy anything up to
        text    #the first "text"
        \s*     #optional spaces
        \(      #opening (
        (.*)    #content inside () greedy -> $1
        \)      #closing )
        \s*$
    /x;

    #processing only the captured content with removed outside ()
    #remove outside ' or " and extra spaces
    my $inside = $1;
    $inside =~ m/
                #at the begining of "line"
        ^\s*    #optional spaces
        ["']?   #optional " or '
        \s*     #optional spaces

        (.*?)   #content - non greedy -> $1

                #at the end of "line"
        \s*     #optional spaces before the closing ' "
        ['"]?   #optional closing " or '
        \s*$    #optionalny spaces
    /x;

    $inside = $1;
    $inside =~ m/
        ^(\w+)  #any word at the start -> $1
        \s*     #optional spaces
        \(      #opening (
        \s*     #optional spaces
        ['"]?   #optional ' or "
        \s*     #spaces
        (.*?)   #the content inside ' " -> $2
        \s*     #any spaces
        ['"]?   #optional "'
        \s*     #sp
        \)      #closing )
        \s*     #spaces
        (\w+)$  #word at the end -> $3
    /x;

    print "=$1= =$2= =$3=\n";
}
__DATA__
text (aaa (text) ccc) 
text ( aaa (text) ccc )
text ( ' aaa (text) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa (text) ccc " )
text (aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc) 
text ( aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc )
text ( ' aaa ( " text " ) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc " )
```

Questions:

1. is it possible join all 3 above regexes into one?
2. if yes, this is possible universally? So possible combine **ANY** number of subsequent matching regexes with capture-groups into *one* regex? (mean only `m//` matching with capture groups and not subsequent substituting regexes)
3. if yes, when is more desirable to use one regex instead of more? When is e.g. faster more regexes and when one big one?

Ps: im aware the existence of the [Text::Ballanced](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Text-Balanced-2.02/lib/Text/Balanced.pm), but this question is more about the "regex possibilities".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot just combine regexes together. Sometimes you can, and sometimes, you cannot. Oftentimes when you can, the regex will end up being longer. For instance, for the ones you have above, you could maybe use something like this:

```
^\w+\s*\(\s*(?:(')|("))?\s*(\w+)\s*\(\s*((?(1)"|'))?\s*(\w+)\s*\4?\s*\)\s*(\w+)\s*(?(1)'|")?\s*\)$
```

[Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pA7oT2)

The above also makes sure the correct quotes are being used (can't use double quotes inside double quotes for instance). The required groups are in `$3`, `$5` and `$6`. And also on. An example on [ideone](https://ideone.com/E5Kcbb).

I'll comment only some parts:

```
^\w+         # Beginning + function name
\s*
\(
\s*
(?:(')|("))? # Capture either single or double quote
\s*
(\w+)
\s*
\(
\s*
((?(1)"|'))? # If a single quote was captured, now match double, and vice versa. Capture
\s*
(\w+)
\s*
\4?          # Use the 4th capture from above comment
\s*
\)
\s*
(\w+)
\s*
(?(1)'|")?   # Use what was used in first quoting character
\s*
\)$
```

Whether it is more desirable to use one or more regex is up to the user. If they can do it in one and they are not worried about it being maintained, then for sure.

If they can make it in one and still explain it well, why not?

It is to be noted that the longer the regex, the more it is prone to errors, catastrophic backtracking and the more it could be difficult to understand.

Longer regexes might not be necessarily slower than smaller regexes either. There are tools that can make things behave much faster; atomic groups, possessive quantifiers, negated classes are some.

Comment: Fair enough :) Can you please show one example, (where are only `m//` and capture groups), whrere ___isn't___ possible to have only one regex and need two subsequent?

Comment: @cajwine It would have more to do with regex's limitations. For instance, perl regex doesn't support variable width lookbehinds. Say, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2725356/1578604). For this particular case, you would be much better off with more than one regex instead of making a monster one to do it (I really don't think it's possible, especially if there are more conditions applied to the question).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    /text \((['" ]*)(\w+)\s*\((['" ]*)(\w+)\3\)\s*(\w+)\1\)/ ;
    say "=$2= =$4= =$5=";
}
__DATA__
text (aaa (text) ccc) 
text ( aaa (text) ccc )
text ( ' aaa (text) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa (text) ccc " )
text (aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc) 
text ( aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc )
text ( ' aaa ( " text " ) ccc ' ) 
text ( " aaa ( ' text ' ) ccc " )
```

**output:**

```
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
=aaa= =text= =ccc=
```

Comment: OP, in case you're not aware, the `\1`, `\2`, `\3` are known as **backreferences**, and allow you to refer to a group captured in the very same expression.